# how to make dialog like google keep in pure js and css

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog, google-keep

how can i create dialog effect like google keep.i tried to debug the css but without any success.
is there code example out there ?

i see that they using hidden position fixed modal that triggering on click but how they calculate the position.

[image: modal open animation]

[image: modal open]

[image: modal close]

Comment: Can you please include some of your code, or else tell us which library you're using to create a modal?

Comment: Your screenshots are confusing. Can you please label `The screenshot of your current code.` and `The screenshot of your desired result`?

Comment: Check [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-a-google-keep-clone-with-vue-and-firebase-pt-2) out. It is not perfect, but it is similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a modal, you can use a library called Swal. Swal, however does not look like keep's popups, so I've restyled it below.

script links you must reference to:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@sweetalert2/theme-material-ui/material-ui.css">`
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/>`
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>`.
 You may also wish to visit Google Fonts and pick a nice `font-family`. Test this pop-up by clicking run this snippet.

```js
const MySwal = Swal.mixin({
    //background: "rgb(10,10,10)",
    background: "white",
    showCloseButton: true,
    backdrop: "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)",


    showClass: {
        popup: "animate__animated animate__fadeInDown med"
    },

    hideClass: {
        popup: "animate__animated animate__fadeOutUp fast"
    },

    width: "95vw"

});
```

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.js" integrity="sha512-HBD0cOZJYcymSn0H0CnN3VBhQLdiH8imucm16ZQ792TT2n48u6nmX+T7hZTCwmzIrgMt76x4rHhR7KkZqhIGxA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>
    <script src="alpha.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" id="iconshort">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@sweetalert2/theme-material-ui/material-ui.css">



    <script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<button onclick="MySwal.fire('Title','Content')">LAUNCH POP-UP</button>
</body>
```

```
const MySwal = Swal.mixin({
    //background: "rgb(10,10,10)",
    background: "white",
    showCloseButton: true,
    backdrop: "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)",


    showClass: {
        popup: "animate__animated animate__fadeInDown med"
    },

    hideClass: {
        popup: "animate__animated animate__fadeOutUp fast"
    },

    width: "95vw",

    willOpen: function() {
        open_audio.play();
    },

    willClose: function() {
        confirm_audio.play();
    }

});
```

Comment: hey thanks for the response. but the animation is not like the modal in google keep. do you have better example ?

Comment: @user8987378 Can you show us an example or clip of the desired animation? Even a URL and instructions would be fine.

Comment: @user8987378 - you can have a look at this library: https://animate.style/

Answer (score 4):

This is what i could make out of your question(pure JS and CSS).
[image]

## Below is the code

```js
var example_note = document.getElementsByClassName('example_note')[0];
var close_btn = document.getElementById('close_btn');
example_note.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('background_change')[0].style.display = "block";
  document.getElementsByClassName('display_block')[0].style.display = "block";
  example_note.style.display="none";
}

close_btn.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('background_change')[0].style.display = "none";
  document.getElementsByClassName('display_block')[0].style.display = "none";
  example_note.style.display="block";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'arial';
}

.example_note {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 1px 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: white;
}

.example_note h1 {
  font-size: 23px;
}

.display_block {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 450px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transform-origin: 0 25%;
  animation: show_block 0.2s 1;
}

@keyframes show_block {
  from {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)scale(1);
  }
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 390px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

button {
  float: right;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-weight: bold;
  outline: none;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #E3E3E3;
}

.background_change {
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.6;
  animation: show_back 0.5s 1;
}

@keyframes show_back {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="example_note">
  <h1>Example Note</h1>
</div>
<div class="background_change"></div>
<div class="display_block">
  <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" style="font-size: 25px;">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="name" value="Example Note" style="font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;">
  <br>
  <button id="close_btn">close</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @ac_mini what about hide effect?

Comment: @AminM I just imitated the effect as shown in the Question's GIF image

Comment: @ac_mini i know,is it possible to edit your answer and add hide effect?

Answer (score 3):

This answer is plain JavaScript and CSS (no libraries), and produces the following effect:

[image]

A full working example is contained in the following snippet (best previewed full screen):

```js
function openModal(noteEl, modalEl, modalContainerEl) {

        // Compute and apply the transform to deform the modal to cover the note with a transition to make it animate
        const transform = computeTransform(noteEl);
        modalEl.style.transform = transform;
        modalEl.style.transition = 'transform 250ms';

        // Setup the modal background animate in too
        modalContainerEl.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
        modalContainerEl.style.transition = 'background-color 250ms';

        // Show the modal
        modalContainerEl.classList.add('modal-container--open');

        // Put the rest in a setTimeout to allow the styles applied above to take
        // affect and render before we overwrite them with new ones below
        setTimeout(function () {
          // Remove the transform to allow the modal to return to it's natural shape and position
          modalEl.style.transform = 'none';
          modalContainerEl.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.5)';
        }, 0)
      }

      function computeTransform(noteEl) {

        // Modal positions here are hardcoded to match styles set in CSS
        const modalTop = 150;
        const modalLeft = (document.body.offsetWidth / 2) - 300;
        const modalWidth = 600;
        const modalHeight = 150;

        // Get note div's position relative to the viewport
        const notePosition = noteEl.getBoundingClientRect();
        
        // Compute a CSS transform that moves the modal to match the note's position
        const translateX = notePosition.left - modalLeft;
        const translateY = notePosition.top - modalTop;
        const scaleX = notePosition.width / modalWidth;
        const scaleY = notePosition.height / modalHeight;

        return `translateX(${translateX}px) translateY(${translateY}px) scaleX(${scaleX}) scaleY(${scaleY})`;
      }

      // Handle click events using event delegation
      document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

        // Handle click events on note elements (open modal)
        if (event.target.className === 'note') {

          // Get a reference
          const modalContainerEl = document.querySelector('.modal-container');
          const modalEl = document.querySelector('.modal');
          openModal(event.target, modalEl, modalContainerEl);
        }

        // Handle click event on modal background element (close modal)
        if (event.target.classList.contains('modal-container')) {
          event.target.classList.remove('modal-container--open');
        }
      })
```

```css
body {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 100%;
        color: #333;
      }

      .note {
        flex: 0 0 200px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;

        border: 1px solid #CCC;
        margin: 12px;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }

      .modal-container {
        display: none;

        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;

        background-color: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.5);
      }

      .modal-container--open {
        display: block;
      }

      .modal {
        position: absolute;
        top: 150px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -300px;
        width: 600px;
        height: 150px;
        
        transform-origin: top left;
        will-change: transform; /* makes the animation run smoother */

        background-color: #EEE;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css" />

      

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      
      

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="note">1</div>
    <div class="note">2</div>
    <div class="note">3</div>
    <div class="note">4</div>
    <div class="note">5</div>
    <div class="note">6</div>
    <div class="note">7</div>
    <div class="note">8</div>
    <div class="note">9</div>
    <div class="note">10</div>
    <div class="note">11</div>
    <div class="note">12</div>
    <div class="note">13</div>
    <div class="note">14</div>
    <div class="note">15</div>
    <div class="note">16</div>
    <div class="note">17</div>
    <div class="note">18</div>
    <div class="note">19</div>
    <div class="note">20</div>

    <div class="modal-container">
      <div class="modal">
        Modal
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The trick is to apply a CSS transform to the modal in order to deform into the shape/position of the clicked note *before showing the modal*. We can then remove the transform and use a CSS transition to get it to smoothly animate into it's natural shape/position.

We calculate the transform as follows:

```js
function computeTransform(noteEl) {

  // Modal positions here are hardcoded to match styles set in CSS
  const modalTop = 150;
  const modalLeft = (document.body.offsetWidth / 2) - 300;
  const modalWidth = 600;
  const modalHeight = 150;

  // Get note div's position relative to the viewport
  const notePosition = noteEl.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  // Compute a CSS transform that moves the modal to match the note's position
  const translateX = notePosition.left - modalLeft;
  const translateY = notePosition.top - modalTop;
  const scaleX = notePosition.width / modalWidth;
  const scaleY = notePosition.height / modalHeight;

  return `translateX(${translateX}px) translateY(${translateY}px) scaleX(${scaleX}) scaleY(${scaleY})`;
}
```

And we apply it as follows:

```js
function openModal(noteEl, modalEl, modalContainerEl) {

  // Compute and apply the transform to deform the modal to cover the note with a transition to make it animate
  const transform = computeTransform(noteEl);
  modalEl.style.transform = transform;
  modalEl.style.transition = 'transform 250ms';

  // Setup the modal background animate in too
  modalContainerEl.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  modalContainerEl.style.transition = 'background-color 250ms';

  // Show the modal
  modalContainerEl.classList.add('modal-container--open');

  // Put the rest in a setTimeout to allow the styles applied above to take
  // affect and render before we overwrite them with new ones below
  setTimeout(function () {
    // Remove the transform to allow the modal to return to it's natural shape and position
    modalEl.style.transform = 'none';
    modalContainerEl.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.5)';
  }, 0)
}
```

Note the `setTimeout` between applying and removing the transform. This is important as otherwise the transform will never actually be applied.

See the snippet for the full details, but also of note: the `transform-origin: top left;` style on the modal is important to make the transform computation work.

Answer (score 2):

I did like the example above, wich worked perfectly. I added opacity to de card selected to remove erase the card from the screen when it is clicked

```
<style type="text/css">

    body {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 100%;
        color: #333;
    }

    .note {
        flex: 0 0 200px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;

        border: 1px solid #CCC;
        margin: 12px;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .modal-container {
        display: none;

        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;

        background-color: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.5);
    }

    .modal-container--open {
        display: block;
    }

    .modal {
        position: absolute;
        top: 150px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -300px;
        width: 600px;
        height: 150px;

        transform-origin: top left;
        will-change: transform;
        /* makes the animation run smoother */

        background-color: #EEE;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openModal(noteEl, modalEl, modalContainerEl) {
        // Compute and apply the transform to deform the modal to cover the note with a transition to make it animate
        const transform = computeTransform(noteEl);
        modalEl.style.transform = transform;
        modalEl.style.transition = 'transform 250ms';

        // Setup the modal background animate in too
        modalContainerEl.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
        modalContainerEl.style.transition = 'background-color 250ms';

        // Show the modal
        modalContainerEl.classList.add('modal-container--open');
        noteEl.style.opacity = 0;

        // Put the rest in a setTimeout to allow the styles applied above to take
        // affect and render before we overwrite them with new ones below
        setTimeout(function () {
            // Remove the transform to allow the modal to return to it's natural shape and position
            modalEl.style.transform = 'none';
            modalContainerEl.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.5)';
        }, 0)
    }

    function computeTransform(noteEl) {

        // Modal positions here are hardcoded to match styles set in CSS
        const modalTop = 150;
        const modalLeft = (document.body.offsetWidth / 2) - 300;
        const modalWidth = 600;
        const modalHeight = 150;

        // Get note div's position relative to the viewport
        const notePosition = noteEl.getBoundingClientRect();

        // Compute a CSS transform that moves the modal to match the note's position
        const translateX = notePosition.left - modalLeft;
        const translateY = notePosition.top - modalTop;
        const scaleX = notePosition.width / modalWidth;
        const scaleY = notePosition.height / modalHeight;

        return `translateX(${translateX}px) translateY(${translateY}px) scaleX(${scaleX}) scaleY(${scaleY})`;
    }

    // Handle click events using event delegation
    let cardSelected;
    document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        // Handle click events on note elements (open modal)
        if (event.target.className === 'note') {
            // Get a reference
            cardSelected = event.target
            const modalContainerEl = document.querySelector('.modal-container');
            const modalEl = document.querySelector('.modal');
            openModal(event.target, modalEl, modalContainerEl);
        }

        // Handle click event on modal background element (close modal)
        if (event.target.classList.contains('modal-container')) {
            event.target.classList.remove('modal-container--open');
            cardSelected.style.opacity = 1;
        }
    })


</script>
```

```
<div class="note">1</div>
<div class="note">2</div>
<div class="note">3</div>
<div class="note">4</div>
<div class="note">5</div>
<div class="note">6</div>
<div class="note">7</div>
<div class="note">8</div>
<div class="note">9</div>
<div class="note">10</div>
<div class="note">11</div>
<div class="note">12</div>
<div class="note">13</div>
<div class="note">14</div>
<div class="note">15</div>
<div class="note">16</div>
<div class="note">17</div>
<div class="note">18</div>
<div class="note">19</div>
<div class="note">20</div>

<div class="modal-container">
    <div class="modal">
        Modal
    </div>
</div>
```